# Adding a Stripe subscription through API

Tags: javascript, python, stripe-payments, zapier, stripe.net

I am trying to automate the creation of a customer and adding a subscription. I can create the customer through Zapier but I don't really know how to use Python or Javascript to add a subscription or invoice. I can pass in all the data I need into variables like the plan Id and invoice amount. Does anyone have experience with this?

Comment: I'd recommend reading Stripe's detailed documentation https://stripe.com/docs/subscriptions/quickstart to better understand how all of this works, or use a third-party https://stripe.com/works-with/categories/recurring-payments

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I have gotten this far but don't understand the syntax error I'm getting.


https://api.stripe.com
import stripe
stripe.api_key = "sk_test_kLyQtpKGLBRmorVmYCToOdai"
stripe.InvoiceItem.create{
customer=input['custid'],
amount=input['opponboarding'],
currency="usd",
description="Onboarding Fee"
}
subscription=stripe.Subscription.create{
customer=input['custid'],
items=[{'plan':input['oppplan']}],
}

Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  
SyntaxError: invalid syntax (usercode.py, line 8)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a subscription request if you have the `customer_id` and `plan_id`. If you want to do this with Zapier, you can make a POST request using the `fetch` library in the Code (Javascript) app.

Pass the `customer_id` and `plan_id` in the Input Data.

[image: input data config]
Encode your secret key from Stripe in Base64. You can use [this site](https://www.base64encode.org/) to encode your key. Replace the encodedAPiKey in the code below and paste it into Zapier.

When this code step runs, it will create a subscription for the customer.

```js
const url = 'https://api.stripe.com/v1/subscriptions';

//Replace with Base64 encoded secret key from Stripe.
const encodedApiKey = "c2tLsfdGVzdF9aYlFNVjdBSzE3Tm1sTVdMVjkwVWdWTz";

const headers = {
    'Authorization': `Basic ${encodedApiKey}`,
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
};

fetch(`${url}?customer=${inputData.customer_id}&items[0][plan]=${inputData.plan_id}`, {method:'POST',
        headers: headers
       })
.then(res => res.json())
.then(json => {
  console.log(json);
  callback(null, json);
})
.catch(callback);
```

You will find documentation for this on Stripe [here](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/quickstart#create-subscription).

***Note:*** If this code gets called multiple times, it will create multiple subscriptions for the customer. You might want to add some code to handle that or setup your Zaps in a way that this step doesn't get called twice.

Hope that helps!